# Selected combinations between the values of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I have two lists `a` and `b`. Then I try to find all three-element combinations between the values of the lists, and only those in which there are values from the list `b`. For now I do it in the following way:

```
import itertools as it

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6]

for i in range(len(b)):
    a.append(b[i])

c = []              
for j in it.combinations(a, 3):
    if 5 in j or 6 in j:
       c.append(list(j))

# output:
# [[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [1, 5, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6], [3, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Unfortunately, with large lists, this is an ineffective way, because the condition of existence of elements from the list `b` is located behind a loop with the function`it.combinations`, which in such a system is executed entirely regardless of the condition. What in the case of large lists heavily overloads the calculation.

Is it possible to obtain such a result differently?

Comment: Don't you want all two-length combinations of `b` plus each of `a`, and all two-length combinations of `a` plus each of `b`?

Comment: why not, the result would be the same :) interesting as with time activities on large lists.

Comment: In that case something like `it.chain(it.product(it.combinations(a, 2), b), it.product(it.combinations(b, 2), a))` would get you an iterator of `((1, 2), 5), ((1, 2), 6), ...` then you could process the tuples into lists. You could also think about whether you really *need* all of the output in one list.

Comment: I do not necessarily need it on one list. it's more important to me that it works in an explicit loop, because with large lists it could be an overloading system.

Comment: because later I check a condition on every single sub-list.

Comment: What do you mean by *"an explicit loop"*? What do you mean by *"could be an overloading system"*? What *"condition"*, and can't that be a `map` or `filter`? The whole point of `itertools` and iterators in general is that you *don't* have to get one large list, you can evaluate them lazily.

Comment: sorry my english is not very good :) yes, `itertools` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
import itertools as it

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6]

c = []
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in it.combinations(b,i):
        for k in it.combinations(a,3-i):
           c.append(j+k)
```